# Spring MVC project with hibernate can' understand how to use in jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am studying Spring MVC, and I have a problem with understanding how to use my classes in jsp, here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class BusinessController {
@Autowired
private BusinessService businessService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("business", new Business());
    map.put("businessList", businessService.listBusiness());

    return "business";
}

@RequestMapping("/find/{businessDate}")
public String listContactsByDate(@PathVariable("businessDate") Map<String, Object> map, String businessDate) {

    map.put("businessByDate", new Business());
    map.put("businessByDateList", businessService.listBusinessByDate(businessDate));

    return "businessByDate";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "redirect:/index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBusiness(@ModelAttribute("business") Business business, BindingResult result) {

    businessService.addBusiness(business);

    return "redirect:/index";
}

@RequestMapping("/delete/{businessId}")
public String deleteBusiness(@PathVariable("businessId") Integer businessId) {

    businessService.removeBusiness(businessId);

    return "redirect:/index";
}
}
```

And here is my jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
<title><spring:message code="label.title" /></title>
</head>
<body>


    <h2>
        <spring:message code="label.title" />
    </h2>

    <form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="business">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="businessDate">
                        <spring:message code="label.date" />
                    </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="businessDate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="description">
                        <spring:message code="label.description" />
                    </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="description" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message code="label.addbusiness"/>" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

    <form:form method="post" action="/find/{$businessDate}"
        commandName="businessByDate">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="businessDate">
                        <spring:message code="label.date" />
                    </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="businessDate" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <c:if test="${!empty businessByDateList}">
        <table class="data">
            <tr>
                <th><spring:message code="label.date" /></th>

                <th><spring:message code="label.description" /></th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${businessByDate}" var="business">
                <tr>
                    <td>${businessByDate.businessDate}</td>
                    <td>${businessByDate.description}</td>
                    <td><a href="delete/${businessByDate.id}"><spring:message
                                code="label.delete" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>

    </form:form>

    <h3>
        <spring:message code="label.businesses" />
    </h3>
    <c:if test="${!empty businessList}">
        <table class="data">
            <tr>
                <th><spring:message code="label.date" /></th>

                <th><spring:message code="label.description" /></th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${businessList}" var="business">
                <tr>
                    <td>${business.businessDate}</td>
                    <td>${business.description}</td>
                    <td><a href="delete/${business.id}"><spring:message
                                code="label.delete" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

And, here is my service implementation class:

```
@Repository
public class BusinessDAOImpl implements BusinessDAO{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addBusiness(Business business){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(business);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Business> listBusinessByDate(String businessDate){
    String hql = "from Business B where B.date = :business_date";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("business_date", businessDate);
    return query.list();        
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Business> listBusiness(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Business").list();
}

public void removeBusiness(Integer id){
    Business business = (Business) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
        Business.class, id);
    if (null != business) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(business);
    }
}
}
```

Without the part of jsp, where I try to list businesses for date everything works fine, I can add a business and it will be immediately listed in a table below, but if I add a part with businessByDate I'll get

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'businessByDate' available as request attribute
```

How can I solve that? Thank you

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's coming out of this form tag:

```
<form:form method="post" action="/find/{$businessDate}"
    commandName="businessByDate">
```

It looks like you only do:

```
map.put("businessByDate", new Business());
```

In the method that is this form's action.  You need to add that object to the map in the method that actually loads the page!

Comment: So, I should rewrite my '@RequestMapping("/index") listContacts(Map<String, Object> map)' method into listContacts(Map<String, Object> map, String businessDate) method, so it  would be like that: map.put("business", new Business());
  map.put("businessList", businessService.listBusiness());
map.put("businessByDateList", listContactsByDate(map, businessDate);
  return "business";

Comment: Can I create one ModelMap and use it for all data I want to use in my view? And if I can, where should I declare it?

Comment: If you annotate a method with @ModelAttribute then it will run on every request that comes into the controller and you can use it to set things up.